# On what SE site should I ask a question about student apartments in Munich, Germany?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to ask a question about what to think about when moving to München, which block(s) to avoid. What is a reasonable price, if there is particular websites for student apartments.

Where should I ask a question like this?

I saw a similar question here [Renting a flat in the UK with a student](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/52145/renting-a-flat-in-the-uk-with-a-student)
but I did not find the question similar enough for me to ask on money.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Minor note, SE sites are not "forums". Forums denote chat and discussion which are generally discouraged.

Answer (score 3):

It feels to me like a [shopping request](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), and those are generally a bad fit for SE sites.

Answers to your question will be outdated quite quickly and will not be useful to a lot of people, since everything can change in a few months or with slightly a different budget.

I am not familiar with any site accepting your specific question, but given the above reasons, I doubt any site will fit.

Answer (score 1):

This will be on topic in [Travel.SE](//travel.stackexchange.com/), and actually there are already two similar questions:

- [Apartment in Munich](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23451/apartment-in-munich)
- [Where can I find short term apartment rental offers in Berlin?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14448/where-can-i-find-short-term-apartment-rental-offers-in-berlin) (about Berlin, but close enough)

The above are for short term apartments, but asking for long term/student apartsments is also on topic on that site, e.g. [Student dorms in Stuttgart (Germany)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27115/student-dorms-in-stuttgart-germany) got a good score and fair answers.

Comment: Both seem short term questions (traveling like behavior), not a permanent stay with specific neighborhoods, etc. Of all, Travel still seems the only (somewhat) fit.

Comment: @Patrick true, found some for long term, see my edit. :)

Comment: I'll give you a bike and then you decide how *close enough* Berlin and Munich are ...

Comment: @rene I prefer walking, more sightseeing this way. :-D

Comment: I'll send you some hiking gear ... with your latest edit you can check-out Stuttgart on the way ....